# How can I transfer tables and records in a database to classes and objects using JPA?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

First of all, Hi, 
as you know, without writing any `sql` command, just using `java`, `spring data jpa`, creating classes and fields, `JPA` repository to create our tables, we automatically increase the id and associate the tables. But how can this be done? In other words, how can I transfer tables, colomns and classes created by `sql` to classes and objects? Is there a way? Can you show me if there is one?

Comment: Have you read any documentation or at least some articles about Hibernate? Have you done any tutorial? Do a couple of tutorials and if you still have questions, then ask. But not before you have done at least some effort.

Comment: @mentallurg As I mentioned in the question, I only registered java classes as tables. If you know why don't you point the source?

Comment: Here on SO it is expected that everyone before asking a question has done at least some effort to find the answer. Have you at least tried to find a tutorial using Google?